# Change just one input field with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code like this:

```
<script>
(function() {

  window.inputNumber = function(el) {
    var min = el.attr('min') || false;
    var max = el.attr('max') || false;

    var els = {};

    els.dec = el.prev();
    els.inc = el.next();

    el.each(function() {
      init($(this));
    });

    function init(el) {

      els.dec.on('click', decrement);
      els.inc.on('click', increment);

      function decrement() {
        var value = el[0].value;
        value--;
        (value<1) ? value=1 : '';
        if(!min || value >= min) {
          el[0].value = value;
        }
      }

      function increment() {
        var value = el[0].value;
        value++;
        if(!max || value <= max) {
          el[0].value = value++;
        }
      }
    }
  };
})();

inputNumber($('.input-number'));
</script>
```

but this will change every input field when I click on one decrement or increment... But I need to be separated and dynamic, here is html:

```
<div class="quantity">
    <span class="input-number-decrement" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span><input type="text" step="4" min="" max="" name="" value="0"  class="input-number" size="4" />
<span class="input-number-increment" style="margin-left: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
</div>
```

I can have more then one input field, and all need to work separately... Any solution?

Comment: You can use name attribute of input HTML tag in your function to change value of a particular field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
els.dec = el.prev();
els.inc = el.next();
```

[`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) will get all the preceding and following elements of the matched elements in `el`.

Remove this step completely and use

```
function init(el) {
  el.prev().on('click', decrement);
  el.next().on('click', increment);
  // ...
```

instead.

```js
(function() {
  window.inputNumber = function(el) {
    var min = el.attr('min') || false;
    var max = el.attr('max') || false;

    el.each(function() {
      init($(this));
    });

    function init(el) {
      el.prev().on('click', decrement);
      el.next().on('click', increment);

      function decrement() {
        var value = el[0].value;
        value--;
        (value < 1) ? value = 1: '';
        if (!min || value >= min) {
          el[0].value = value;
        }
      }

      function increment() {
        var value = el[0].value;
        value++;
        if (!max || value <= max) {
          el[0].value = value++;
        }
      }
    }
  };
})();

inputNumber($('.input-number'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <span class="input-number-decrement" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left">-</i></span>
  <input type="text" step="4" min="" max="" name="" value="0" class="input-number" size="4" />
  <span class="input-number-increment" style="margin-left: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right">+</i></span>
</div>
<div class="quantity">
  <span class="input-number-decrement" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left">-</i></span>
  <input type="text" step="4" min="" max="" name="" value="0" class="input-number" size="4" />
  <span class="input-number-increment" style="margin-left: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right">+</i></span>
</div>
<div class="quantity">
  <span class="input-number-decrement" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left">-</i></span>
  <input type="text" step="4" min="" max="" name="" value="0" class="input-number" size="4" />
  <span class="input-number-increment" style="margin-left: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right">+</i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your code like that:

```
$('.input-number').each(function(){
    inputNumber($(this));
})
```

instead of:

```
inputNumber($('.input-number'));
```

See [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/268hu84r/1/)